# How to allow only positive integer using argparse

Tags: python

I have it to where if the user doesn't input a num2, it will take 1 as a default number. However, I'm also trying to implement where if the user DOES input a number, it has to be above 0.

```
import argparse
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument('-n2', '--num2', action='store_true', default=1, choices=range(0))
```

I've looked around and found that choices=ranges allows me to set a range for the number, however, i get an error saying

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'
```

Comment: Maybe the error refers to a bad argument rather than a bad keyword. Try a non-empty container, like `range(5)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `type` to check for positive integer input as follows:

```
import argparse


def check_positive(value):
    try:
        value = int(value)
        if value <= 0:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("{} is not a positive integer".format(value))
    except ValueError:
        raise Exception("{} is not an integer".format(value))
    return value


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=check_positive)

args = parser.parse_args()
print('args: {}'.format(args.foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

After making few parameter changes i was able to resolve the issues. I'm not sure if this is the same thing that you want though

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n2', '--num2',  default=1, type=int,choices=range(0))
```

I just removed action and it works fine. I'm also new to python so let me know if its not what you needed

Comment: Are you sure range(0) is right? That means range(0,0) so nothing would be allowed.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's requirement.